# Touch input not working well in unity game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a space shooter game with a space ship which I want to move by finger movement.

I attached the below script with it but it does not works well. At the start the ship moves normally with finger movement, but over time the spaceship begins to react very fast to even slight finger movements.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Boundary
{
public float xMin, xMax, zMin, zMax;
 }


public class Playercontroller : MonoBehaviour {
public Rigidbody rb;
public float speed;
public Boundary boundary;
public GameObject shot;
public Transform shotSpawn;
public float fireRate;
private float nextFire;

void Update(){

    if(Input.GetButton("Fire1") && Time.time>nextFire)
    {
        nextFire = Time.time + fireRate;
        //GameObject clone=
        Instantiate(shot, shotSpawn.position, shotSpawn.rotation);
        AudioSource audio = GetComponent<AudioSource> ();
        audio.Play ();


}
}


void FixedUpdate () {
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
    float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
    float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");
    if (Input.touchCount >0) {
        moveHorizontal = Input.touches [0].deltaPosition.x;
        moveVertical = Input.touches [0].deltaPosition.y;

        Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);
        rb.velocity = movement * speed;

        /*  if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved) {
            Vector2 touchDeltaPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition;
            transform.Translate(-touchDeltaPosition.x * speed, -touchDeltaPosition.y * speed, 0);
        }

    */

        rb.position = new Vector3 (
            Mathf.Clamp (rb.position.x, boundary.xMin, boundary.xMax),
            0.0f,
            Mathf.Clamp (rb.position.z, boundary.zMin, boundary.zMax)

        );

    }
}
}
```

Comment: If you want to move it on finger down, why are you updating velocity of rigidbody? My guess is that rapid changes in velocity is messing up with the movement.
On a side note, you should move 'rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();' to Start method.

Comment: it does not works in this format

Comment: `Input.touches[0].deltaPosition` is measured in *pixels* whereas traditional joystick/mouse input is clamped [0-1]. Check the standard mobile assets asset package for a mobile virtual joystick prefab.

Comment: but I want to move object by finger movement, and not by joystick

Comment: You need to use @-mentions to notify people you have a reply. *We* don't need to because you're automatically notified of comments to your own posts.  In any case: `Input.touches[0].deltaPosition` is *still measured in pixels,* if that isn't what you want, you need to do some sort of conversion to sensible values.